# Get Latest Version shortcut in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, keyboard-shortcuts

Would love to have a keyboard shortcut that get's the latest for a solution I am working on inside Visual Studio 2008 from source control.

Can't find one in the documents anywhere!

In addition would be good if I could get other source control shortcuts for checking in pending changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your own... tools -> options -> environment -> keyboard

Look in particular for:

- File.GetLatestVersion
- File.GetLatestSolutionFiles
- File.CheckIn

and add a new shortcut at the bottom

Comment: Great, never knew about that very useful screen! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Visual Studio macro that will enumerate all active keyboard shortcuts to a nicely formatted HTML page, here:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000412.html

But as Marc pointed out, you might have to add your own .. not sure these things you want are actually bound by default to anything.

Answer (score 0):

The compatibility of keyboard shortcuts that work on a fresh install can be useful, unfortunately in this case it's a bit convoluted:

alt,v,p,(home) alt,f,r,l

Which selects the solution explorer, home to get to the root if necessary then get latest from the file menu.